# Pack of resources in one big file with XNA

Tags: xna

Is it possible to pack all the little .xnb files into one big file?
Given the level of abstraction of the XNA Framework I though this would come out of the box but I can't find any well integrated solution.

So far the best candidate is [XnaZip](http://xnazip.codeplex.com/) but in addition to having to compile the resources in a post-build event, and a little trouble porting the game to XBOX I have to rename all the references to resources I have already implemented.

Comment: Why do you have to rename references to your resources? After answering your question, I had a cursory glance at `XnaZip`; it seems like it should be a drop-in replacement -- aside from the missing `System.IO.Compression` namespace.

Comment: In the readme of the XnaZip project it says: 'After that you can load your objects like this:
Texture2D earth = content.Load<Texture2d>(ResourceId.Earth);' But now that you mention maybe I misinterpreted it and means 'you may' instead of 'you have to'. I will give it a try.

Comment: Why do you want to pack these files together?

Comment: for easier distribution when you have tons of files and to hide internal resource names from plain sight

Comment: @PrinceCharles also keep in mind that copying one big file is much faster than copying many smaller ones (especially off of optical media).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible, but you either have to:

- Find a library that does it for you, or
- implement it yourself.

XNA lets you do the latter by deriving from the `ContentManager` class and replacing the `OpenStream` method; in fact, the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.content.contentmanager.openstream.aspx) explicitly says:

> ```
> protected virtual Stream OpenStream (string assetName)
> ```
>
> Opens a stream for reading the specified asset. Derived classes can replace this to implement pack files or asset compression.

In the override version of `OpenStream`, one would simply return a compatible `Stream` that read the requested asset data from a pack file, rather than opening a `FileStream` from disk.

The tricky part is that you have to actually build the pack file yourself, incorporating the `xnb` files output via the content build pipeline. You could build a Content Pipeline Extension to do this, or find some other method, depending on what your goals are.